# gif animation play only once onclick and mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gif

I have two images: static and animated. I am trying to play that animated image but only once. After that, it will change to static one.

My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#targetDIV_three').bind('click mousedown', function () {
        srcToGif2 = "http://demo.pink-squid.co.uk/christmas/s3.gif";
        $("#divthree_three").attr('src', srcToGif2);
    });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/33Sqd/

Currently, it is not stopping after the first animation.

---

Latest fiddle with single animated loop gif.

http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/4rC8D/1/

Now can't see the animation though the img src is changing.

Comment: Give me a good reason why this gif should ever stop playing?

Comment: Because there are few more in the queue same like this tentacles and bells. The user should not be confused by too many animations playing at the same time.

Comment: Don't loop the gif....

Answer (score 8):

If you want this animated GIF to be played only once, modify it in Photoshop. Go to Window > Timeline, then select looping options (bottom left corner):

[image]

Save for web as GIF and voila!

Comment: Is the image cached with the old version in the browser?

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra there are three solutions and you claim that neither one does work. Are you sure you tried your best?

Comment: You are not getting my point.http://demo.pink-squid.co.uk/christmas/s3_loop_once.gif the image is perfect. There is no problem with animation. The problem is when you click that black border box the static image should change to single loop animated image. But it is not.Check my latest fiddle

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Thank You! Worked like a charm for me as well. What a little nugget to know!

Answer (score 2):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33Sqd/5/)**

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#targetDIV_three').bind('click mousedown', function () {

[].slice.apply(document.images).filter(is_gif_image).map(freeze_gif);

function is_gif_image(i) {
return /^(?!data:).*\.gif/i.test(i.src);
}

function freeze_gif(i) {
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var w = c.width = i.width;
var h = c.height = i.height;
c.getContext('2d').drawImage(i, 0, 0, w, h);
try {
    i.src = c.toDataURL("image/gif"); // if possible, retain all css aspects
} catch(e) { // cross-domain -- mimic original with all its tag attributes
    for (var j = 0, a; a = i.attributes[j]; j++)
        c.setAttribute(a.name, a.value);
    i.parentNode.replaceChild(c, i);
}
}
      });
});
```

For getting desired effect you can setTimeout to trigger click event `#targetDIV_three`

Comment: Did you checked the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Chnage your code to this. A timeout is set to set the old gif again.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#targetDIV_three').bind('click mousedown', function () {
        srcToGif2 = "http://demo.pink-squid.co.uk/christmas/s3.gif";
        $("#divthree_three").attr('src', srcToGif2);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#divthree_three").attr('src', "http://demo.pink-squid.co.uk/christmas/s3_bg.gif");
        },900);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/33Sqd/2/

Comment: It is working.If I change the animated image to loop once then it is not working.

Comment: I have used a single loop image but still it is not animating.http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/4rC8D/1/